Caffeine cache failed with worker threads
Caffeine cache value not read when multiple threads try to access it simultaneously
Quick repo
https://github.com/ethanalef/caffeine-cache-example
Try to run CacheTest::threadedTest() to replicate the problem
Aims
A costly IO method would be frequently accessed by multiple threads at the same time. Using L1 caching would a relief.
Situation
I have several classes for their purpose:
CaffeineConfig: Cache TTL = 300 seconds
CacheHelper: get the cached AtomicInteger, if value is get from cache, then the integer should not be incremented
Worker: work to get the atomicInteger
Manager: use ScheduledExecutorService to start the threading workers A, B, C to work
CacheTest: simulate the Manager class
Expected
When manager starts, first worker to get value = 0 and cached. second and third worker should get the value (=0) from the cache.
Actual
When manager starts, first worker to get value = 0 and cached. second and third worker get the incremented value rather than from the cache.
Findings

I created another worker at sometime during the runtime, the value is indeed cached.
The strange behavior only happens when threads try to get/access the value at the same time.
From ChatGPT, it explains it might be that the cache is not shared among workers due to Threadlocal properties but I cannot understand; Bito also cannot provide reasonable answer.

Question
Does anyone have the same experience could share how should I do to fix this problem?

You want sync=true on your cache annotation. Unfortunately the default is to use racy read-load-put which is causing your undesirable behavior.

@BenManes I was suspecting this. I added synchronized to the method but no help. I tried sync=true and it works fine! I will try to see if any problem else. Thank you but the way!

@BenManes You should post it as an answer since it solves the problem.
